# Blank screen when zooming in/out in MapView in Android 2.2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, zooming, android-2.2-froyo

I have an application that puts some overlays in a MapView of the Google Maps api for android working perfectly in Android 1.6, and when I tested in an Android 2.2 (LG Optimus One) when zooming in/out (fast) the MapView fails to render the overlays and map, showing nothing, just a blank screen.

Now, i have noticed that if one is connected to the internet, the map reloads after downloading the maptile, fixing the problem. But, if the devices fails to connect to the internet, the MapView doesn't restore the view, having sometimes to restart the app. I checked the android log but didn't found any warnings/errors.

I have checked with an "empty" application that only adds one overlay in an empty MapView, and the problem persisted, and I couldn't reproduce the problem in the Google Maps application.

I would like to know if someone else can reproduce this issue or has a fix for it.

Comment: I've got the exact same problem! Changing from 1.6 to 2.2 and then the map seems to have trouble getting tiles when zooming fast..

Comment: @pecka85 It's seems like a bug of the MapView implementation then. Still, there has to be a workaround to it somewhere. I searched in http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API?pli=1 and http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Inthttp://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Stars+ApiType+Internal&cells=tilesroduced+Fixed+Summary+Stars+ApiType+Internal&cells=tiles but found nothing related, so im thinking of posting the bug there too.

Comment: One thing that must be related to this problem:  I've noticed that once the map gets into this state where it suddenly refuses to draw map tiles and overlays anymore, the Projection object you get when calling getProjection() stops working.  I've been using its toPixels() method, but this method starts returning the same GeoPoint no matter which parameters I give it.  Very odd...

Comment: I didn't knew that behavior of getProjection(). What do you mean that the object got by getProjection() stop working? maybe one can trigger something by that (like recreating the MapView?)

Comment: Can you please post some code here...